# Hexadecimal clock in Portable Class Library c#

Tags: c#, time, hex, portable-class-library

I want to create a class in the portable class library that manages the current time in [*true* hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_time) time, not simply sexagesimal time represented by hex digits.

What is my best method of operation here if I want programs that use it to be able to update themselves in real time?

Here is what I've considered:

- A static converter class that converts standard DateTime into
  resulting hex time (this may be difficult to use for a program updating itself in real time
- A class that calls events when the hex clock changes hours, minutes, seconds, etc. by keeping time within the class itself (this may lead to lossy arithmetic and compromise the accuracy of the clock)

I can't use a lot of the features of standard .NET because I want this to be a portable library. I am new to the asynchronous features of .Net 4.5 and have some preliminary experience with simple multi-threaded applications. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you want to provide a reusable library that is useful in many scenarios, I would go with option A, as it is more generic. Can you tell more about your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the converter method below to perform the conversion:

```
const int HexUnitsInDay = 16 * 16 * 16 * 16;
const int SecondsInDay = 24 * 60 * 60;

public static string ConvertToHexTime(TimeSpan tm)
{
  int hexTime = Convert.ToInt32(tm.TotalSeconds * HexUnitsInDay / SecondsInDay);
  return String.Format(".{0:X}", hexTime);
}
```

Usage example:

```
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToHexTime(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay));
```

To update the screen on a regular basis, you can use a system timer-event-generation class.

In WPF you can use the `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` class for that, e.g. [a clock in c# wpf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470768/a-clock-in-c-sharp-wpf-application)

In Winforms you can use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` class for that, e.g. [Run a Digital Clock on your WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678162/run-a-digital-clock-on-your-winform)

In both cases: set the update-interval to 1318 milliseconds (this roughly equals `SecondsInDay / HexUnitsInDay`).